# Docker scrapy spider AttributeError: 'TutorialPipeline' object has no attribute 'cur'

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, vps

Hello im trying to run my scrapy on a VPS server using docker when i try to run it return an error:

```
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
web_1        | ['tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline']
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (shutdown)
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Scraper close failure
web_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 82, in crawl
web_1        |     yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
web_1        | psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
web_1        |  This probably means the server terminated abnormally
web_1        |  before or while processing the request.
web_1        |
web_1        |
web_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1        |
web_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
web_1        |     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
web_1        |   File "/scrapy_estate/tutorial/pipelines.py", line 19, in close_spider
web_1        |     self.cur.close()
web_1        | AttributeError: 'TutorialPipeline' object has no attribute 'cur'
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
web_1        | {'finish_reason': 'shutdown',
web_1        |  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 8, 7, 4, 3, 806923),
web_1        |  'log_count/ERROR': 1,
web_1        |  'log_count/INFO': 6}
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (shutdown)
web_1        | Unhandled error in Deferred:
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
web_1        |
web_1        | 2018-08-08 07:04:03 [twisted] CRITICAL:
web_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
web_1        |     result = g.send(result)
web_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 82, in crawl
web_1        |     yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
web_1        | psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
web_1        |  This probably means the server terminated abnormally
web_1        |  before or while processing the request.
web_1        |
```

my pipelines.py

```
import psycopg2
class TutorialPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        hostname = 'localhost'
        username = 'postgres'
        password = '123' # your password
        database = 'real_estate'
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cur.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur.execute("insert into estate(estate_title,estate_address,estate_area,estate_description,estate_price,estate_type,estate_tag,estate_date,estate_seller_name,estate_seller_address,estate_seller_phone,estate_seller_mobile,estate_seller_email) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(item['estate_title'],item['estate_address'],item['estate_area'],item['estate_description'],item['estate_price'],item['estate_type'],item['estate_tag'],item['estate_date'],item['estate_seller_name'],item['estate_seller_address'],item['estate_seller_phone'],item['estate_seller_mobile'],item['estate_seller_email']))
        self.connection.commit()
        return item
```

EDIT:
My docker-compose.yml so i can run port on the VPS server:

```
version: "3"
services:
  interface:
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '123'
    volumes:
    - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    expose:
    - "5432"
    networks:
      - webnet
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: zerolin/scrapy_estate:latest
    build: ./tutorial
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
    networks:
      - webnet
  splash:
    image: scrapinghub/splash
    ports:
     - "8050:8050"
    expose:
     - "8050"
networks:
  webnet:
```

I ran the spider with scrapy crawl estate on my local pc and it ran fine without encounter this error.

It can't seem to get self.cur from open_spider function to other function in the same class :/

```
AttributeError: 'TutorialPipeline' object has no attribute 'cur'
```

But when i use it on the server it encountered his error. Im confused , any helps would be appreciate :)

Seem to be something wrong with my connection to postgres on the docker side of the VPS ,even though i checked its the same postgres username, password

Answer (score 1):

Your log says:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
>   This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>   before or while processing the request.

Your pipeline fails to open connection:

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    # ...
    self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)
    self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
```

Make sure you can establish connection to your postgres server. Maybe hostname or password is wrong?

Comment: that's probally it i'm checking my docker-compose.ym file(will post it in edit) but i did put the same pg_user and pg_password